# How to get the name of a two-way bound React input element

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a React form with a large number of inputs that use React two-way binding mechanism e.g.

```
<input valueLink={this.linkState('companyName')} type="text"/>
```

I would like to create a way to click on a field and show its name, something like:

```
<input valueLink={this.linkState('companyName')} onClick={function(e){alert(e.target.name)}/>
```

However for fields with linkState name is blank. I have scoured through all properties and cannot find the name anywhere. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get the name attribute. How about something like this `e.target.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to return null. The name attribute is not set explicitly but via linkState, that may be the reason.

Comment: the linkState will not set any name attribute automatically as far as i know. If set explicitly, yes, definitely.